# Individual Email Results not appearing for Salesforce Send Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

We are sending Salesforce Send Emails from Marketing Cloud using a Salesforce Data Extension.

We can view the Email Send from the 'Email Sends' tab within Sales Cloud, however the 'Individual Email Results' are always 0. Refer to screenshot below.

We're using Person Accounts, but I'm not sure if that's the issue. I have this working on another client account (also using Person Accounts) without issue, but it's just not working for this specific Sales Cloud account.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or can you suggest anything to isolate the cause of this issue?

[image: email send detail]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per Eliot's request, I am sharing my test results. Have tested 28 scenarios for when tracking shows up. The baseline requirement is to use the 18 character SFID as Subscriber/ContactKey - apart from that, you can see the results from this link:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AudxPOAgo7PDzH8-69sHt4_-Vp7p

Comment: Hi Kenneth, you url no longer works.

Comment: Hey @AndrejLučanský - thanks for the heads up, link is updated. Also, note, there is a way to get tracking via automation studio email sends, you just have to make sure integration user is integrated, that way, a SF Email Send activity will show up.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to:

1. Use `PersonContactId` field (from the Person Account) as the Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud.
2. Ensure that you are sending to a data extension which is stored in the Salesforce Data Extension folder (or sending via Journey Builder) (tracking will not work if you are sending emails to a data extension in the regular data extension).

We've validated this and tracking works as expected.

Comment: I've amended #2 a bit - is there a way to drop a file into the answers? I have an excel sheet with more than 25 scenarios for when tracking is visible and when it isn't :)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, you can't upload Excel sheets as answers, and SFSE doesn't give you much options for displaying tabular data. However, if you can provide a public Dropbox link, github repo or similar to the Excel file, please post as another answer as I'd be keen to review these different scenarios that you mention.

Comment: Added the test results :)

Answer (score 3):

Normally, Individual email results are not updated if the contact/lead id is not selected as the subscriber key in data extension. You can cross check the subscriber key in the data extension or in the Tracking -> Salesforce Sends that would give the subscriber key against which the send has been performed. Since you are using person accounts, person account id/contact id should be the subscriber key for Salesforce to update Individual Email Result.

Other reason could be the refresh interval of the tracking attributes. In the Marketing cloud connect configuration page in Salesforce, check the refresh interval of the tracking attributes. Individual email results will be updated only at the refresh interval specified in connector setup and are not created after email send. If its more than one hour, try setting up it to one hour. Also, i have noted during salesforce email sends that Email results are not updated immediately even if we click on Request tracking immediately and it typically take at least 20 minutes. Not sure of the technical reason behind it though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, we're using the Person Account ID as the Subscriber Key, so not sure what's the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be working on this particular flow within the next 30 days or so, and have gone to great lengths to clarify the necessities with Salesforce.

They are saying:

- Salesforce DE
- Salesforce Send
- SubscriberKey = Lead Id or Contact Id

Now a person account in Salesforce has both an Account Id and a Contact Id, and when asking the support directly about this, they said it should be based on contact ID, even though it's a person account.

Based on what you're mentioning, it sounds like you're using the account id? (this would equate the visible part of the URL in Salesforce).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/60873)

Comment: I disagree - I'm proposing that he's using the wrong ID for subscriber key, which - when using the correct one - would be a solution? :)

Comment: You're getting these responses from the review queue because you have phrased your post as a question. Also note, you never have to `@mention` the OP.

Comment: I've just added an answer with validated steps to enable email tracking for Person Accounts.

Comment: @Kenneth Wagner: Hi Kenneth, your link is unfortunately not available anymore. Could you please re-upload your file with test scenarios? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @Gajewski - link updated :)