# Tracking data from Marketing Cloud to Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We have configured triggered send feature in sales cloud to send mails to clients. I want to track the data (mail opened, clicked, etc) from Marketing Cloud back to sales cloud. I know the Individual Email Result object in sales cloud is used for capturing data from Marketing Cloud. But the issue is, we are not getting any tracking data getting created in sales cloud (i.e.) No Individual Email Result record getting created after trigger send execution. Please provide me inputs to resolve the issue.

Comment: I've run into the same issue which I documented [in this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141235/individual-email-results-not-appearing-for-salesforce-send-emails). You can have a look at the answer to this question and see if that helps. We've just engaged Salesforce Services Team (at a cost) to try and resolve this for us as the regular support channel has been unable to assist.

Comment: Hey @EliotHarper Thanks for the response. I've checked the link. Am using contact id as the subscriber key for Salesforce (confirmed from Tracking > Triggered Sends). Also refresh interval of the tracking attributes from Marketing cloud connect configuration page is set to 'Hourly'. So am doing things in correct way. But am not getting any Individual Email Result record for the emails sent through Triggered send feature. :( Any inputs here is highly appreciable.

Comment: I'm stuck on this issue just as you are, but will share any insights from our engagement with Salesforce professional services when I have them.

Comment: That would be really helpful. Even i raised case with SFMC support, waiting for their response.. But in general, support team is taking too much time to respond!

Comment: @EliotHarper Did you find any solution for the above issue? Could you please update. Meanwhile i chased SFMC support and their response was, they were working on it!!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few root causes which has resolved this behaviour for us:

1. The [Salesforce System User](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/preconfiguration/) (formely 'Tracking User') needs to be setup in Sales Cloud as an API User.
2. If you are using a Person Account in Sales Cloud, you will need to use the PersonContactId field as the Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud.
3. When sending to Contacts, you need to use 'Contact ID' as the Subscriber Key.