# Track Salesforce Triggered Send - Marketing Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

I configured a triggered send in Salesforce in order to send an email when a new record is created (in this case new activity related to a contact) following the steps written in the [documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/). I am able to see tracking send into Marketing Cloud and some records inside the tab "Aggregate Link Level Details", but at the same time I cannot see anything inside "Individual Email Results" in Salesforce.

Do you have any suggestion about this issue?

Comment: Are you using Person Accounts in Salesforce?

Comment: Hi @EliotHarper Yes, i am using them. In the triggered send configuration firstly i selected a custom object as 'Object' and, secondly, Client as 'Recipient Lookup'. Then i also tried to substitute Client with the field Contac, but i obtained the same result.

Comment: I think your question could be a duplicate. Please can you review [my answer to this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141235/individual-email-results-not-appearing-for-salesforce-send-emails/154494#154494) and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

For person accounts, make sure you are using the `PersonContactId` as your subscriber key.

Also in your email setup, you will need to check "**Send Tracking Results to SalesCloud.**"

You will need the data extension in the **Salesforce Data Extension** folder in order to see this option.