# Individual Email Results not appearing for shared data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

We have been using different BU and so shared data extensions that comes from the Mother BU.
We would like to use only shared data extensions (because we want to send from Email Studio and Journey Builder at the same place) but at the same time Individual Email Results in Salesforce.
I have been explaining that I have to use Salesforce Data extensions.
Is there any trick to use Shared Data extensions only that will fulfill Individual email results ?
I saw that [Individual Email Results not appearing for Salesforce Send Emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141235/individual-email-results-not-appearing-for-salesforce-send-emails) but it does not help.
Thanks for your precious help

Comment: It should work if you use Shared DEs in Journey Builder and do a single send journey. Make sure to tick (on the email send activity) the checkbox where it says to send tracking results to Sales Cloud. Give it a try :-)

Comment: Thank you, it is clicked by default in the email activity in Journey Builder. I have the option "send tracking results to Sales Cloud" for journey but not for email studio send with Shared DE. This is what I need. Thank you

Comment: Would the Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder not do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should simply be able to use the "Shared Salesforce DataExtenison" folder

[image]

Comment: Yes thank youfor your help I am aware for Shared SF DE folder but it means we use to many different folders which is not user-friendly. I was hoping a unique folder and so a way to do so.