# Marketing Cloud Connect - IERs not created

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We have integrated SFMC and CRM. The MMC for sure works. In most cases everything looks good. But we have a few cases where data were not sync correctly.

We did some tests where we triggered a journey to 3 test contacts and check if IERs for them will appear in CRM. In most cases it works. But we have some journeys where only Triggered Send Objects were created in CRM without related IERs. Sometimes it's just for one of the three tested contacts, sometimes for the whole journey audience.

Does anyone have an idea what I should check?

Comment: I would check the email activity in the journey and make sure that "Send tracking results to sales cloud" was already checked in Delivery Options tab https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: @DucLe Yeah, it was checked for sure. And I think that thanks to this we have Triggered Send objects populated in CRM but for some reason IERs are not created for these sends.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141235/individual-email-results-not-appearing-for-salesforce-send-emails

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj thank you for the link I checked it but it doesn't help us :( We did over 40 tests for the same 3 contacts and only in a few cases IERs were not created in CRM for them. We always had the same SubscriberKeys (CRM Contact IDs).